# Reading a PowerPoint slide Speaker Notes from Office Add-In (web)(office.js)

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-2016

I'm creating a PowerPoint Add-in (JavaScript based Office Add-in for the web, aka Office.js), and need to read the Notes (Speaker Notes) for the current slide.

I can access the shapes and other content on a slide (reading and inserting new content), but I cannot see how to access the Speaker Notes.
Is this a supported scenario? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Each slide has a .NotesPage property that returns, for all practical purposes, a slide. The quick and dirty way to get there is to get the slide's .NotesPage.Shapes(2) which will be the notes text placeholder. Or .NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text to get the notes text.  This can get messed up if someone's edited the notes page to remove then replace the text placeholder.  I don't know whether JS has access to the same object model as VBA, but this might give you a starting point.

Comment: Office.js doesn't support access to the speaker notes.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for filling in that piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Rick Kirkham, this feature was not available and is still not available as of July 2023.

I was wondering if there was already a feature request for that, but after doing a [quick search](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&filter=location&location=idea-board:Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform&q=Powerpoint%20notes), I couldn't find anything on the dedicated Microsoft 365 Developer Platform forum (previously known as UserVoice).

So, I've posted a new feature request here :

[Allow reading and editing of PowerPoint presenter notes via the Office.js API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-reading-and-editing-of-powerpoint-presenter-notes-via-the/idi-p/3881489#M1890).

Comment: This isn't an answer (and there's no programming question here). Please don't respond to off-topic questions. Also, asking people to go to another site to vote on something... isn't what Stack overflow is for.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - I've removed the asking for upvote. However, can you elaborate on why this isn't a programming question?

Comment: It’s because the only thing the OP included was a set of requirements and then a request for sample code. That’s the problem. You can’t just post requirements and have this site fulfill them. You have to show all details *including* what’s been tried (code, data, errors, etc) - a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidMakogon - If I understand your second comment correctly, you are saying that it is a programming question, but it doesn't meet SO quality standards. I not necessarily disagree, but when this type of question has an answer it's usually 1 or 2 lines of code, so it's not like they gave requirements and expected us to write a full program. Plus, the need to provide a minimal reproducible example is mostly needed when someone wants to help with debugging an issue, not when they are asking to accomplish a simple thing that should be obvious.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: how should the OP include example code for a feature which isn't currently available in some API? Note this Q&A is subject on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425692/how-to-efficiently-avoid-have-they-added-this-feature-yet-questions), maybe you want to contribute there?