# Is it possible to utilize the Office.js for reading and writing text into presenter notes of a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, add-in, powerpoint-addins

I've created a powerpoint add-in and I need to insert text into the presenter notes. Is it feasible to use the Office.js library to read/write text in PowerPoint add-in presenter notes? I've searched in different forums without any luck.

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71169553/reading-a-powerpoint-slide-speaker-notes-from-office-add-in-weboffice-js#comment125818154_71169553), I'd say no.

Comment: Thank you for answering DecimalTurn. I saw the post you mentioned but I needed to check if there was an update about it. Next time, I'll comment on the post.

Comment: The best place to ask or track progress on Office.js related features is on the Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Forum, so I've made a post [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-reading-and-editing-of-powerpoint-presenter-notes-via-the/idi-p/3881489#M1890) if you want to follow up on this later. I've also added this answer to the original question with the comment I mentioned above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [customer related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow) shouldn't be discussed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerPoint APIs in the Office JavaScript library (aka Office.js) do not support reading or writing to the presenter notes.

Comment: Thank you Rick Kirkham! I hope they add that in the future.